# Combine two columns of text with NaN in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nan

I want to combine two columns as below

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd    
data = pd.DataFrame({ 'a' : [np.nan, 'abc'], 'b' : ['abc', 'abc']})
data['c']=data['a']+' '+data['b']
data

     a   b    c
0   NaN abc   NaN
1   abc abc abc abc
```

The problem is in NaN, i want get

```
Nan + abc = abc
```

I can do like this

```
data = pd.DataFrame({ 'a' : [np.nan, 'abc'], 'b' : ['abc', 'abc']})
data = data.replace( np.nan, '',regex=True)
data['c']=data['a']+' '+data['b']
data   

    a     b    c
0       abc abc
1   abc abc abc abc
```

but it's not always convenient. Are there ways to combine like?

```
NaN + abc = abc
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> data['c']=data['a'].fillna('') + ' ' + data['b'].fillna('')
>>> data
     a    b        c
0  NaN  abc      abc
1  abc  abc  abc abc
```

However, do note that `data['c'][0] == ' abc'`. You'd have to use `.str.strip()` to strip off whitespace if needed.